# c# lastindexof throwing an exception

Tags: c#, string, lastindexof

I am unsure why this is throwing an exception. This code is supposed to take the cursor position then get the last index of space or enter to pick out a the last single word typed.It sometimes throws an exception of out of range. Is the selection start value going to be higher than number of characters in the string? I am unsure what exactly is causing this. I put the if statement to avoid doing an index of characters that dont exist ... but that didn't improve or worsen it one way or the other.

```
        private string word()
    {
        char[] array1 = { '\n', ' ' };
        int end = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        int strt = 0;
        if (textBox1.Text.LastIndexOfAny(array1)!=-1)
        {
             strt = textBox1.Text.LastIndexOfAny(array1,end);
        }



        if (strt==-1) { strt = 0; }

        return textBox1.Text.Substring(strt, end - strt);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: I'd look into the value of `end`. The error tells you exactly what's going on. `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the selection` How long is `textBox1.Text`?

Comment: Because 'end' refers to an index that your string in textBox1.Text does not have...

Comment: Make sure that the `end` is not greater than the length of `textBox1.Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kbkt4sh(v=vs.110).aspx),

> `String.LastIndexOfAny Method (Char[], Int32)` Reports the zero-based
>   index position of the last occurrence in this instance of one or more
>   characters specified in a Unicode array. The search starts at a
>   specified character position and proceeds backward toward the
>   beginning of the string.

In your case the `textBox1.SelectionStart` will give you the current position of the cursor in the Textbox. Let the string in the TextBox be `"sampl"` and the cursor is at end of the text, so the SelectionStart will give you the value `5`. Please note that the string in the box is of length `5` but it doesn't have a character at index `5` since it follows `0` based indexing.

Hence while accessing this code `strt = textBox1.Text.LastIndexOfAny(array1,end);` the `5` is not a valid index in the string. that causes the error here.

So use the following lines to get the cursor position(`end`), then your code will works as you expected

```
int end = 0;
if (textBox1.Text.Length > 1)
    end = textBox1.SelectionStart - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you get this exception when `startIndex` specifies a position that is not within this instance.

So, check the `end` value in your case and make sure that it is less than `textBox1.Text.Length`

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the first `LastIndexOfAny()` call into a local variable and then subtract it from `end` to get the value for the second call to `LastIndexOfAny()`.

```
private string word()
{
    char[] array1 = { '\n', ' ' };
    int end = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    int strt = 0;
    var lastIndex = textBox1.Text.LastIndexOfAny(array1);
    if (lastIndex !=-1)
    {
         strt = textBox1.Text.LastIndexOfAny(array1, end - lastIndex);
    }



    if (strt==-1) { strt = 0; }

    return textBox1.Text.Substring(strt, end - strt);

}
```